# Show that if Z(N) = {e} and Z(G/N) = {e}, then Z(G) = {e}.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group and let N be a normal subgroup of G. Show that if Z(N) = {e} and Z(G/N) = {e}, then Z(G) = {e}.

Z(G) is the set of elements in G that commute with all of G.

I have no idea what to do!

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest here to prove the contrapositive: if $Z(G)\neq \{e\}$, then either $Z(N)\neq \{e\}$ or $Z(G/N)\neq \{e\}$. To see this, suppose $Z(G)\neq \{e\}$, and suppose that $Z(N)=\{e\}$. Then $Z(G)\cap N=\{e\}$ because otherwise any element both in the center of $G$ and in $N$ would be in the center of $N$. Thus there is an element $z\in (G-N)\cap Z(G)$.

Consider a surjective homomorphism $\phi:G\to G/N$ with kernel $N$ and let $g\in G$. Then $\phi(g)\phi(z)=\phi(gz)=\phi(zg)=\phi(z)\phi(g)$. Since $g$ was arbitrary and $\phi$ is surjective we have that $\phi(z)\in Z(G/N)$, so $Z(G/N)\neq \{e\}$.